# Slider that increased center slide width. (Slider plugin suggestions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to create slider when it slide center slide width must have incresed and the two slide next to it stay on normal slide.

I have tried one using slick slider.

Here is the code pen link that I have tried.([Click here](https://codepen.io/sameeraliyanage/pen/ejLqpB))

But this is not smooth and the slide next to center slide not showing properly.

**If anyone know some better slider for do exact kind of this please suggest me a link.**

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: "0px",
  speed: 1000
  
});

$('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

  $(slick).next().css({
    'margin-left':'auto'
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #102131;
}
.slider {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.slider .slide {
  padding: 0px;
}
.slider .slide .child-element {
  transition: all .2s ease;
  background: #0c1c79;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  width: 300px;
}
.slider .slide .child-element .imgWrap img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.slider .slide .child-element .desc {
  display: none;
}
.slider .slide.slick-active:last-chid .child-element {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.slider .slide.slick-center .child-element {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-70px, 0px);
          transform: translate(-70px, 0px);
  width: calc(100% + 140px);
  max-width: initial;
}
.slider .slide.slick-center .child-element .desc {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child-element">
       <div class="imgWrap">
         <img  src="https://www.scopecinemas.com/images/movie/dark900x12001.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text">Title1</div>
      <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child-element">
       <div class="imgWrap">
         <img  src="https://www.scopecinemas.com/images/movie/trans900x1200.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text">Title2</div>
      <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child-element">
       <div class="imgWrap">
         <img  src="https://www.scopecinemas.com/images/movie/mi900x1200.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text">Title3</div>
      <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child-element">
       <div class="imgWrap">
         <img  src="https://www.scopecinemas.com/images/movie/Venom900x1200.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text">Title4</div>
      <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child-element">
       <div class="imgWrap">
         <img  src="https://www.scopecinemas.com/images/movie/alpha900x1200.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="text">Title5</div>
      <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The 'no external links without code' restriction is there for a reason. Subverting it will only get your question downvoted and closed.

Comment: The slider is smooth when I test it. What you could do to increase the "quality" of the slide is to make the center image a bit smaller and add a shadow around it. Then you will have a carousel á la iTunes

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Any slider suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try this css for child Element:-

```
html,
body {
  background: #102131;
}
.slider {
  width: 1240px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.slider .slide {
  padding: 0px;
}
.slider .slide .child-element {
  transition: all .5s;
  background: #0c1c79;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  width: 300px;
  transform-origin: top center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider .slide .child-element .imgWrap img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.slider .slide .child-element .desc {
  display: none;
}
.slider .slide.slick-active:last-chid .child-element {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.slider .slide.slick-center .child-element {
  background: rebeccapurple;
    transform: scale(1.68);
  max-width: initial;
}
.slider .slide.slick-center .child-element .desc {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing i have did, but then its cover the first and last elements.

Comment: that's grate. I will accept it if i couldn't find some other answer. Thank you very much.